# Find peaks (notch & diastole peak)

Tags: python

I have the following plot from some data using Python:

Plotted max-min peak:
[image: Plotted max-min peak]

I'm trying to find another peak between below threshold (maximum of peaks) and up from minimum of peaks. Which is 'o' an 'x' in the picture. By the way, I've filtered the noise and use SciPy.signal find_peak for both (maximum and minimum peak). I was wondering if I can use the same method but looking the peak between below threshold (maximum of peaks) and up from minimum of peaks. Is it possible?

Comment: You could try calculating the second derivative of the signal, then looking for peaks in that. Those would occur when the slope switches from getting shallower to getting steeper, which is what you've marked. These might also be called inflection points.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said first derivative. That will have a local maximum at the points where it switches from falling less steeply to falling more steeply.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp TQ... I tried using the scipy.misc (derivative) but later i realized that its just taking the difference. So can anyone suggest me how to go about calculating the 1st derivative (specifically for the PPG signal)? TQ so much

Comment: Sorry, I didn't take the time to think carefully about this before. For numerical data, the best estimate you can get of derivatives is just the numerical differences. The first derivative of your signal will have a local maximum just before the intermediate peaks. That point is also known as an inflection point, where the curvature goes from concave up to concave down. And at that point, the second derivative will be zero. But that is not quite the point you want. You could try the point where the second derivative has a local minimum, which will be the sharpest downward curvature.

Comment: Another option would be to use some kind of moving linear trend, then find the points where your signal is furthest above that trend. This would be an intuitive definition of a bump within a signal. The moving trend could be calculated just as the mean of two points a certain distance on either side, or a simple moving average (boxcar) centered on your point of interest.